# Смена аудио дорожки на иконку в мобильной версии

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

Есть аудиодорожка, мне нужно сменить всю дорожку только на одну иконку play/stop и чтобы аудио включалась по нажатию этой иконки, только в мобильной версии. Я нашел такое решение, но не знаю как заменить `play/pause` на мои картинки.

css:

```
   @media all and (min-width: 320px) {
        #audioControl {
            display: none;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    }


    @media all and (max-width: 1170px) {
        #audioControl {
            display: block;
        }
    }
```

html:

```
<a href="#" id="audioControl">play!</a>
```

js:

```
    var yourAudio = document.getElementById('yourAudio'),
    ctrl = document.getElementById('audioControl');

    ctrl.onclick = function () {

    // Update the Button
    var pause = ctrl.innerHTML === 'pause!';
    ctrl.innerHTML = pause ? 'play!' : 'pause!';

    // Update the Audio
    var method = pause ? 'pause' : 'play';
    yourAudio[method]();

    // Prevent Default Action
    return false;
};
```

Помогите решить, не знаю как сделать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Допустим, есть картинки с именами img-1.jpg и img-2.jpg в папке img:

```js
var yourAudio = document.getElementById('yourAudio'),
playpauseimg = document.getElementById('playpauseimg');
playpauseimg.onclick = function () {

    // Update the Button
 playpauseimg.src = "img/" + yourAudio.paused ? 'img-1.jpg' : 'img-2.jpg';

    // Update the Audio
    var method = yourAudio.paused ? 'play' : 'pause';
    yourAudio[method]();
};
```

```html
<audio id="yourAudio" src="sound.mp3"></audio>
<img id=playpauseimg src="img/img-2.jpg"/>
```

Comment: не работает почему-то(

Comment: А что пишет консоль? Ещё HTML-код должен быть наверху, а JS ниже.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: pauses is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.ctrl.onclick

Comment: Но в моём коде нед элемента pauses...

Comment: А как получить доступ к картинке через js? Она у меня в папке /img/img-1.jpg. Я попробую реальные картинки вставить, может тогда получится

Comment: у вас есть элемент `paused`. Посмотрите еще раз, пожалуйста

Comment: Нужно прописать путь к картинкам. В общем, я изменил ответ с учётом Ваших имён картинок и пути. **paused** (с буквой **d** в конце) - это не элемент, а свойство аудио, при котором аудио находится в состоянии паузы. Оно используется для выполнения условия, если нажата пауза. Ваш 
 изменённый код я не видел, но там видимо есть обращение к несуществующему элементу **pauses** с буквой **s** в конце, поэтому консоль пишет такую ошибку и код не работает.